# filter array within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of products and i want to filter all those products with the level. The level here is also an array because i have used checkbox so if user selects level 1, a product with level 1 should be shown and if user again selects level 2, a product with level 1 and 2 should be shown. However i am getting all the products instead of the selected level.

**Here is my code**

```
// sample product data
products = [
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "new", status: "online"},
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "1", status: "offline"},
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "1", status: "offline"},
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "2", status: "online"}
]

function productFilterFromLevel({level}) { // level ["new", "1"]
  return products.filter(function(product) {
    return level.filter(function(lvl) {
      return product.sellerLevel === lvl;
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// sample product data
products = [{
  id: "1",
  sellerLevel: "new",
  status: "online"
}, {
  id: "1",
  sellerLevel: "1",
  status: "offline"
}, {
  id: "1",
  sellerLevel: "1",
  status: "offline"
}, {
  id: "1",
  sellerLevel: "2",
  status: "online"
}]

function productFilterFromLevel(level) {
  return products.filter(function(product) {
    return level.indexOf(product.sellerLevel) != -1;
  });
}

console.log(productFilterFromLevel(["new", "1"]));
```

Comment: This worked on my case. Thanks for your help. I forgot indexOf to check in the elements in an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with your filter

```
const productFilterFromLevel = ({level}, products) => products
  .filter(item => level.includes(item.sellerLevel))
```

or without includes you can just filter on the keys like so

```
const productFilterFromLevel = function({level}, products) {
  return products.filter(function(product) {
    return level.indexOf(product.sellerLevel) !== -1
  })
}
```

as you can see the `includes` version is much cleaner but you can always make your own include function:

```
const arrayIncludes = function(array, item) {
  return array.indexOf(item) !== -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects, which is a great use case for [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
// sample product data
products = [
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "new", status: "online"},
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "1", status: "offline"},
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "1", status: "offline"},
{id: "1", sellerLevel: "2", status: "online"}
]

function filter(products, matches) {
  return products.filter(product => {
    return matches.includes(product.sellerLevel);
  });
}

console.log(filter(products, ['new', '1']));

// [
//   {id: "1", sellerLevel: "new", status: "online"},
//   {id: "1", sellerLevel: "1", status: "offline"},
//   {id: "1", sellerLevel: "1", status: "offline"}
// ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/fL8eupoz/3/

Comment: Thanks for answering. However the problem that i have raised in my question is i am not comparing sellerLevel to 1 or new but with level array not a single value.

Comment: @Apprentice, Updated

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy as simple match since you need a comparison of `sellerLevel`:

```
function productFilterFromLevel(level) { // level ["new", "1"]
  return products.filter(function(product) {
    for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
      if (level[i] === 'new') {
        return product.sellerLevel === 'new'
      }
      return +product.sellerLevel <= +level[i]
    }
  });
}
```